# Как считать информацию из бинарного файла?

Tags: c++

Стоит задача: записать простые числа в бинарный файл. Числа берутся из промежутка 1...n. Все сделал, но не получается вывести в консоль числа. То есть считать числа из файла. Помогите найти ошибку.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

bool IsPrime(int num)
{
    for (int i = 2; i < sqrt(num); i++)
    {
        if (num % i == 0)return false;
    }

    return true;
}

int main()
{
    fstream f;
    int n;
    cout << "Input N" << endl;
    cin >> n;

    f.open("f.bin", ios::app/ios::binary);

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (IsPrime(i))
        {
            f.write((char *) &i, sizeof(i));
        }
    }
    f.close();

    f.open("f.bin", ios::in / ios::binary);
    int a;
    while (f.eof())
    {
        f.read((char *) &a, sizeof(a));
        cout << a << " ";
    }
    f.close();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как минимум, не надо делить...

```
ios::app/ios::binary
```

нужно - побитовое ИЛИ:

```
ios::app|ios::binary
```

А вообще, я бы делал так:

```
bool IsPrime(int num)
{
    if (num < 2) return false;
    if (num == 2) return true;
    if (num%2 == 0) return false;
    for (int i = 3; i*i <= num; i+=2)
    {
        if (num % i == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Input N" << endl;
    cin >> n;

    {
        ofstream f("f.bin",ios::binary);

        for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (IsPrime(i))
            {
                f.write((char *) &i, sizeof(i));
            }
        }
    }

    {
        ifstream f("f.bin", ios::binary);
        int a;

        while(f.read((char*)&a,sizeof(a)))
            cout << a << " ";
    }

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Можно и с одним `fstream`, конечно:

```
bool IsPrime(int num)
{
    if (num < 2) return false;
    if (num == 2) return true;
    if (num%2 == 0) return false;
    for (int i = 3; i*i <= num; i+=2)
    {
        if (num % i == 0) return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    int n;
    cout << "Input N" << endl;
    cin >> n;

    fstream f;
    f.open("f.bin",ios::out|ios::binary);

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        if (IsPrime(i))
        {
            f.write((char *) &i, sizeof(i));
        }
    }
    f.close();

    f.open("f.bin", ios::in|ios::binary);
    int a;

    while(f.read((char*)&a,sizeof(a)))
        cout << a << " ";

    f.close();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Да, флаг `app` - неудачный, при очередном запуске будет выполняться дозапись в файл - а оно вам надо?...